# Is there a way in Windows 10 to convert a hex code to its symbol regardless of the program?

Tags: hexadecimal, symbols

I've read many pages that point out that many office applications allow for this by typing the code followed by <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, but frequently, I want to insert a symbol when I'm not in one of those applications, is there a universal way to achieve this? The character map is useless, unless you have time to manually search through all the characters available.

Comment: I would use any Auto Key ... type of applications that allow to define your own keys, and they would convert to your target text wherever you are in windows. You can have a quick look [here](https://techwiser.com/text-expander-apps-for-windows) to pick the one you are comfortable with

Answer (score 0):

Windows (and Linux) OS allow insertion of symbols by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>, holding it while typing the key code, and then releasing it. For example, to get the degree sign, °:

- Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- Type <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>.
- Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

This works independently, *regardless of application*.

Also, if you frequently use international symbols or letters, such as *é* in résumé, you can [easily add an international keyboard for a language](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-add-us-international-keyboard-in-windows-10/) in almost any OS. These use "dead" keys to compose a letter. For example, to get the above *e-accent-grave*, press and release <kbd>'</kbd> and then <kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for the first 256 alt codes.   I've found the alt codes for the characters I frequently use (they were listed on webnots), but since they're outside that range, they yield the wrong symbols.  (For encircled letters, I get chars that could be used to create borders.)

Comment: Look up the Alt codes, e.g., https://altcodeunicode.com/ . Note that a **leading zero** is needed for some.

Comment: The encircled letters are also listed with the same codes on altcodeunicode.com.  Even when I add a leading zero, they aren't working.  They don't even work in the office applications where the hex codes work when I follow them with ```Alt```+```X```.  (Granted, I'm using LibreOffice, not Microsoft Office, but the hex codes worki there.)